# Is there a way to declare a constant inside a computed property in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, computed-properties

I have several properties like this in my Swift 3 code:

```
var dinActive: Bool {
    get { return UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "bo", fallback: true) }
    set { UserDefaults.standard.set (newValue, forKey: "bo") }
}
var spdif1Active: Bool {
    get { return UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "spdif1", fallback: true) }
    set { UserDefaults.standard.set (newValue, forKey: "spdif1") }
}
```

I wonder if I can make this more compact. E.g, I'd avoid repeating the string literal in both getter and setter functions, like with `let s = "bo"`. Is that possible in some way?

*Also, I wonder if I can make this repeated pattern into even shorter code, like I could do with classes and generics, or with a `#define` macro in C. Though, that's probably better asked in a separate question. If you have a suggestion for that and it's not answered on SO yet, just add a comment and I'll make a new question of it.*

Answer (score 0):

you can create a let constant outside of your class for it. For example:

```
//declaring constant outside of class
let SPDif1Key: String = "spdif1"

class YourClass
{
    var dinActive: Bool {
        get { return UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: SPDif1Key, fallback: true) }
        set { UserDefaults.standard.set (newValue, forKey: SPDif1Key) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the obvious answer, but it breaks the locality I like to achieve. I should have pointed out that as the unpopular answer in my question. BTW, no need to write ": String" as that type is implicitly given from the string literal.